# How to convert Array to ArrayList?i don't know whether this work or not..can anyone help me

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm new to Java world. Here is my code:

`OrderElementRequest` is a class which holding the detail of order elements.

`OrderElementRequest[] orderElementRequest;` //Array type defined in

`class OrderElementRequests` which have setter and getter for the same.

`OrderElementRequests orderElementRequests;` //OrderElementRequests type defined in the class PlaceOrderRequest which have setter and getter for the same.

```
List listElement = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(placeOrderRequest.getOrderElementRequests()));
order.setLstOrderElement(listElement);     //order is an object of Order class which contains an Arraylist LstOrderElement of type OrderElement.
```

Now I wanted to convert array of `OrderElementRequests` to `List<OrderElement> LstOrderElement`. Nnow there is a warning:

> Type safety: The constructor ArrayList(Collection) belongs to the raw type ArrayList. References to generic type ArrayList should be parameterized.

*And here is few more information*

**public class OrderProcessorImpl implements IOrderProcessor{**

```
public void placeOrder(PlaceOrderRequest placeOrderRequest) throws Exception{       

    String URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
    String Uname="hr";
    String Pass="hr";
    Connection con=null;
    PreparedStatement prepairedSt=null;


    Order order=new Order();

    order.setOrderDescription(placeOrderRequest.getOrderDescription());
    order.setCreatedDate(placeOrderRequest.getOrderDate());         
    List<OrderElementRequests> listElement = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(placeOrderRequest.getOrderElementRequests())); 
    order.setLstOrderElement(listElement);
```

.
.
.

**public class PlaceOrderRequest {**

```
            String orderDescription;
            Date orderDate;
            OrderElementRequests orderElementRequests;              


            public String getOrderDescription() {
                return orderDescription;
            }
            public void setOrderDescription(String orderDescription) {
                this.orderDescription = orderDescription;
            }.......
```

**public class OrderElementRequests {**

```
        OrderElementRequest[] orderElementRequest;

        public OrderElementRequest[] getOrderElementRequest() {
            return orderElementRequest;
        }

        public void setOrderElementRequest(OrderElementRequest[] orderElementRequest) {
            this.orderElementRequest = orderElementRequest;
        }
```

}
**public class OrderElementRequest {**

```
                String Order_item_name;
                BigDecimal order_item_price;
                Date CreatedDate;
                OrderElementAttributeRequests  orderElementAttributeRequests;       


                public OrderElementAttributeRequests getOrderElementAttributeRequests() {
                    return orderElementAttributeRequests;
                }
                public void setOrderElementAttributeRequests(
                        OrderElementAttributeRequests orderElementAttributeRequests) {
                    this.orderElementAttributeRequests = orderElementAttributeRequests;
                }
```

....

**public class Order {**

```
String orderId;
String orderNumber;
BigDecimal orderTotal;
String orderDescription;
Date createdDate;
Date updatedDate;

        List<OrderElement> lstOrderElement = new ArrayList<OrderElement>();

                    public void setLstOrderElement(List<OrderElement> elements){
                        this.lstOrderElement = elements;
                    }
                    public List<OrderElement> getLstOrderElement(){
                        return lstOrderElement;
                    }
```

.......

Comment: Start using *generics*.

Comment: Provide your exact code rather than describe it. If you have problems with the formatting, somebody will help you.

Comment: thanks for your information...                                       List<OrderElementRequests> listElement = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(placeOrderRequest.getOrderElementRequests())); order.set‌​LstOrderElement(listElement); //now it saying type mismtch..Error:The method setLstOrderElement(List<OrderElement>) in the type Order is not applicable for the arguments (List<OrderElementRequests>)..bcs converted Array type(OrderElementRequests) and list type is not matching..

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) in order to ensure your `List`s contain elements of the correct types.  The message you are seeing is warning you that the `ArrayList` you are constructing could unsafely hold *any* type, not just `OrderElementRequest`.  You use generics to prevent that at compile time.

```
List<OrderElementRequest> listElement = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(...));
```

Comment: List<OrderElementRequests> listElement = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(placeOrderRequest.getOrderElementRequests())); order.setLstOrderElement(listElement);                            //now it saying type mismtch..Error:The method setLstOrderElement(List<OrderElement>) in the type Order is not applicable for the arguments (List<OrderElementRequests>)..bcs converted Array type(OrderElementRequests) and list type is not matching..

Comment: Notice the `<>` after `new ArrayList` - you need to declare both the type and the instance as generic.  Read the linked tutorial for more.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the type to your arraylist so it knows what to expect:

```
List<OrderElementRequest> listElement = new ArrayList<OrderElementRequest>(Arrays.asList(placeOrderRequest.getOrderElementRequests()));
```

Doing this will prevent the compile time warning because you have told the compiler what to expect in this list.  It is not required but it is helpful in preventing problems with your code (like adding objects of different types to the same list).

Answer (score 1):

Start using [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/intro.html) introduced in Java 5.0 (a *long* time ago), instead of sticking to Java 1.4 style coding...

```
List<YourObjectType> listElement = Arrays.asList(array);
```

should work, as well as

```
List<YourObjectType> listElement = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

(which will *copy* it to an `ArrayList`. The first is an array backed list, which will not allow insertions; but will in turn reflect changes to the array.)

Comment: Thing is i'm try to insert content of Array of one type to a ArrayList of Another type...can we do type casting for this?

Comment: If the types are compatible, you can do `existinglist.addAll(Arrays.asList(secondlist))`. If the types don't match, use an appropriate supertype; but double-check your logic that you are doing the right thing. If you have to use a `List<Object>`, you most likely are doing something wrong.

Comment: Note that a `List<OrderElementRequest>` just *is not* a `List<OrderElement>`. It's not even a `List<? extends OrderElement>`, because `OrderElementRequest` does not extend `OrderElement`.